# Footer at bottom

Tags: html, css

After having built 3-4 sites(yeah still an amateur), I'm still dealing with keeping footer at bottom. Here's my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kY8hY/

The footer was just fine until I began building the body and then, when I entered some values to the content, that wall of text, the footer came up.

Here is another jsfiddle which I can keep the footer at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/2J2TH/

You will notice that I took out an entire div (anasayfaicerik) and replaced it with another div (deneme) with the exact same value.

```
<div id="shakingmygoddamnhead>yup</div> stack forces me to do this.
```

What is clashing? Which value of "anasayfaicerik" is clashing with "footer"

I tried deleting everything one by one to see if the problem would go away but no man. It's there unless I delete the whole "anasayfaicerik" div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the content inside `#adadil` is floated, therefore `#adadil` ignores their sizes.

You need a `clearfix` that forces the container to actually contain the floated content.

For example [bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com) `clearfix` looks like the following:

```
  .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
  }
```

And then you simply add the `clearfix` class to `#adadil` div. (No extra `html` would be needed)

## [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/kY8hY/5/)

Comment: This is what happens when i do that or the overflow hidden solution http://jsfiddle.net/4R45u/ I have some text and they stay beneath the footer.

Comment: But my proposed solution doesn't contain `overflow: hidden;`. I've updated my answer with `bootstrap`'s clearfix solution. Which is used by a lot of websites. So I'd consider it an "official" approach. Please give it a try

Comment: I did give it a try :) that overflow part was for the other answerer. Your solution really did expand the content but as you can see in my latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4R45u/1/ , the text at the bottom of the adadil div, (the three columns) are still hidden beneath the footer.

Comment: I'm so ashamed of myself right now... I've set the three column's height to a fixed value when they should've been auto... Thank you much matyas.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the CSS applied to the `#anasayfaicerik` element.

Since its contents are floated, you need to make the container expand to fit its content.

Adding `overflow:hidden` to it fixes it.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kY8hY/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/F8Hf7/2/

I just set

```
#footer {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That just threw my footer to the right side of the page

Answer (score 0):

**JUST ANOTHER WORKING EXAMPLE**

This example is working and it is quite simple I think. The CSS is just an example. This should work with loose divs and also with flexbox items. Also this example is simple "pimpable".

Think about, you have the content of the document.
For example: 'header' and 'content' and 'footer'

(You can have as much elements you want. In this example, you need only the same 'css class name' in the 'html code' for all elements, that are not the footer. In this example the 'class name' for these elements is 'container')

```js
// get footer
const footer = document.getElementById('footer');

// get the footer root height that was computed from default setting
// this is the value that makes the footer always the correct height
// if the windowInnerHeight was smaller than all content in document
const footerRootHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(footer,null).getPropertyValue('height').match(/\d+/));

function setFooterPosition() {

    // get actual dynamic window inner height
    let windowInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;

    // set container to store all document content except footer
    let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

    // new container height
    let containerHeight = 0;

    for ( let i = 0; i < container.length; i ++ ) {

        // get the overall complete container height
        containerHeight += container[i].offsetHeight;

    }
    
    // get height of content including footer root height
    // in case, windowInnerHeight is smaller than content
    let overallHeight = containerHeight + footerRootHeight;

    // set footer height in case that windowInnerHeight is
    // larger than container content stored in the document
    let footerHeight = windowInnerHeight - containerHeight;

    if(windowInnerHeight <= overallHeight){

        // windowInnerHeight is smaller than content
        // > set footer height back to core settings
        footer.style.height = footerRootHeight + "px";
        
    } else {
        
        // windowInnerHeight is bigger than content
        // > set footer height to new dynamic value
        footer.style.height = footerHeight + "px";

    }
}

setFooterPosition();

window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {

        setFooterPosition();
    
    },
);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.content {
    height: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.footer {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
    HEADER
</div>

<div class="container content">
    CONTENT
</div>

<div class="footer" id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
```

The 'event-listener' is just for the case, someone is resizing. I found, that would be useful. You should run it through a 'throttle-function' I guess. I do and it's working like a charm.

I can't test all for sure. That's not possible.

Tested and working in (October 2023):

- Chrome Desktop
- Firefox Desktop
- Chrome Mobile
- Firefox Mobile
- Brave Mobile
- DuckDuckGo Mobile
- Opera Mobile
- Opera Mini Mobile
- UC Browser Mobile
- Edge Mobile
- Mi Browser Mobile
- Vivaldi Browser Mobile

It should work, even when mobile view is taken to Landscape Mode. And I think, you can use "all" kinds of html elements for the content. Just style all with css and you are ready to go.

I put all in the function, if something changes dynamically. So the content can change along with the height of the content and the height of the document.

This is my first post here. So please don't be too hard to me ;) - if something is not correct or not working. I will correct asap. I tried, to keep all simple as possible. Have a nice day.